# Accessing store in Vue3 using Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am building a Vue3 app using TypeScript using Vuex for storing certain data. However I am unable to access the `$store` in the script tag of my main *App.vue* or other components in general.

My vuex store looks somewhat like:

```
export default createStore({
  state: {
    members: [
      { id: 1, name: "Alice", role: "admin", email: "abc@example.com" }
    ] as Member[],
    size: 5
  },
  mutations: {
    addMember(state, member: Member): void {
      state.members.push(member);
    }
  },
  getters: {
    membersList(state) {
      return state.members;
    },
  }
})
```

The script tag of my App.vue file:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
//import MemberCard from "./components/MemberCard.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
   // MemberCard
  },
  data() {
    return {
      
    };
  },
  computed:{
    func(){
      return this.$store.getters.membersList;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I am still learning the ropes on Vue3 and TypeScript. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not supposed to be used as `this.$store`, and `this` is the legacy of 2. It naturally has problems with TS. Stick to composition API.

Comment: This breaking change (removal of `this.$store`) is [documented here](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/migrating-to-4-0-from-3-x.html#typescript-support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vuex File**

```
export default createStore({
  state: {
    members: [
      { id: 1, name: "Alice", role: "admin", email: "abc@example.com" }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getMembers: ({ members }) => members,
  },
})
```

**Template File**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { onMounted } from "vue";
export default {
  setup(){
     const store = useStore();
     onMounted(() => {
      console.log(store.getters.members);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Please check these codes, i hope it will be worked. I also added, please check [vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) official site for better reference.

Comment: The mounted part I think is somewhat of an issue, cause this example leads to an undefined output.
Somewhat like:
Vue warn]: Property "memberList" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <App>

Comment: The `onMounted` hook in this example isn't pertinent to the original question. Use the Composition API's `computed()` to get the `store.getters.members`, and return that from `setup()` to 
expose it to the template.